# Авторизация VK, access_token expires_in=0. Как быть?

Tags: вконтакте, vkontakte-api, сеть

Здравствуйте!

Нужно следущее: отправить запрос на авторизацию в VK.
Получить access_token в ТЕЛЕ HTML сообщения-ответа.
Именно в теле, это важно. Запрос на авторизацию шлю так:

```
NetSend("http://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=+++&scope=12&redirect_uri=http://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&v=5.5&response_type=token", Response);
```

Где Response это - OnResponse(char *response, int length){...}.
Параметры - ответ сервера и длина сообщения ответа. Всё работает... В ответ приходит только:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
      <title>OAuth Blank</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     Пожалуйста, <b>не копируйте</b> данные из адресной строки для сторонних сайтов. Таким образом Вы можете <b>потерять доступ</b> к Вашему аккаунту.
   </body>
</html>
```

Как видно ацесс токена тут нет, он приходит в строку браузера( У меня нет в распоряжений функций, которые смогли бы принять ацесс токен как-то по особому. Беда, не могу авторизоваться.  Ладно, как решил проблему:

https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id=+++*&client_secret=+++&v=5.5&grant_type=client_credentials

Получаю в ответ:

```
{"access_token":"4f3d15484f3d15484f60a960734f03cb3444f3d4f3d15481c07d11a045de4505f7cf2e3","expires_in":0}
```

Только этот access_token не работает, почему???

Comment: Возможно, конечно. Как работает приложение? Расскажите по шагам. Кто куда заходит, что делает.

Смотрите параметр `redirect_url` в [авторизации Standalone приложений](https://vk.com/dev/auth_mobile). Перенаправляйте пользователя на страницу на своем сайте (его домен надо прописать в настройках приложения), и там отдавайте сначала свою страницу с JS, который возьмет токен из адресной строки, а затем AJAX'ом запостит его тут же в скрипт на вашем сайте, где вы его и сохраните.

Comment: Работать должно так: 
1) Есть мобильное устройство и только оно, на нем кнопка "Разместить чей-то пост на своей странице"
2) При нажатии на кнопку нужно разместить чей-то(это забито в программе) пост на странице vk. 
     Как это должно выглядеть: нажал на кнопку, вышло окно vk, пользователь ввел в него свои данные, пришел ацесс токен в теле html ответа от сервера, приложение обработало этот html, изьяло токен и репостнула на странице владельца телефона чей-то пост.

Comment: Вот это работает:

https://api.vk.com/method/execute.POST?1&access_token=++++
 

 //http://oauth.vk.com/authorize?display=mobile&client_id=++++&scope=wall&redirect_uri=http://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&v=5.5&response_type=token

НО, ацесс токе приходит не в теле HTML!!! Как попросить сервер, чтобы он токен засунул в HTML ответ?????

Comment: А зачем вам? JSON распарсить намного проще, чем выкусывать данные из HTML.

Comment: Да у меня огромная проблема, есть только метод принимающий html ответы, больше ничего нет. Это возможно????